# How to remove all planes in ARCore

Tags: arcore, removeall

How do I remove all detected planes in ARCore and restart the detection of them? Is this even possible? I searched on Google and Stackoverflow with *arcore remove/delete all planes* and I found nothing useful.

/Edit: I want to have ARCore in the same state after the version check on start up, the grey hand-movement-animation is shown and no planes are detected (so they must be deleted first) and ARCore is trying to detect new planes.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to relaunch the activity, or destroy the session and create a new one?

Comment: Works as a charm with correct intent flags. thanks!

Comment: How did you solve this? What are the correct way of using the intent flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the app as [Clayton Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4077205/clayton-wilkinson) said works, I did it with the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Main.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Maybe restarting activity is solved your problem, but its not a correct  solution overall

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you give some code I can explain better for your case, but you just need to make:

```
frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class).clear();
```

EDIT (Leaving the previous answer for future research)

Now I know that you are using sceneform, you have to restart the activity.
We don't have yet a call like .onPause, .onResume, .clear, etc for this library.

So by now what you can do is restart the activity.

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(HelloSceneformActivity.this, HelloSceneformActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bad idea, results in a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.clear(Collections.java:1116)
        at at.mts.arnatomy.controller.ar.renderable.RestartView.lambda$viewBehaviour$1$RestartView` exception on the code line you provided. Please check my updated question.

Comment: To restart the app you have to add Intent flags, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51820095/10030695

Comment: I did on my without flags. @ManuelTS