# Is there a way to reset ARCore detected surfaces without destroying and remaking the session script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm making an application which uses optional ARCore. This means that I enable and disable the ARCore device on runtime. I noticed that the detected surfaces will still exist even though you disabled and re-enabled the ARCore device.

Is there a way to reset detected surfaces data? I want the users to start fresh every time they open up the AR content.

I have found answers to this in other threads, but all of them involve forcefully destroying the ARCoreSession script from the ARCore device and then re-adding the script back onto it. This seems.. stupid and inefficiënt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete just Detected Planes in your scene (without destroying and recreating an `ArSession`) is not a good practice using ARCore. An alternative to this is deleting all `ArAnchors` what are designed to hold `Renderables`. Although the most robust approach is to destroy a current `ArSession` and create a new one again.

Look at this GitHub issue #253 for further details: [Clear Planes and Anchors](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/253).

and...

Look at StackOverflow post [How to remove all planes in ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788827/how-to-remove-all-planes-in-arcore/51820095#51820095) to find out more.